# Should I be comparing bytes using struct?

Tags: python, file, comparison, byte

I'm trying to compare the data within two files, and retrieve a list of offsets of where the differences are.
I tried it on some text files and it worked quite well..
However on non-text files (that still contain ascii text), I call them binary data files. (executables, so on..)

It seems to think some bytes are the same, even though when I look at it in hex editor, they are obviously not. I tried printing out this binary data that it thinks is the same and I get blank lines where it should be printed.
Thus, I think this is the source of the problem.

So what is the best way to compare bytes of data that could be both binary and contain ascii text? I thought using the struct module by be a starting point...

As you can see below, I compare the bytes with the ==  operator

Here's the code:

```
import os
import math


#file1 = 'file1.txt'
#file2 = 'file2.txt'
file1 = 'file1.exe'
file2 = 'file2.exe'
file1size = os.path.getsize(file1)
file2size = os.path.getsize(file2)
a = file1size - file2size
end = file1size  #if they are both same size
if a > 0:
    #file 2 is smallest
    end = file2size
    big = file1size

elif a < 0:
    #file 1 is smallest
    end = file1size
    big = file2size


f1 = open(file1, 'rb')
f2 = open(file2, 'rb')



readSize = 500
r = readSize
off = 0
data = []
looking = False
d = open('data.txt', 'w')


while off < end:
    f1.seek(off)
    f2.seek(off)
    b1, b2 = f1.read(r), f2.read(r)
    same = b1 == b2
    print ''
    if same:
        print 'Same at: '+str(off)
        print 'readSize: '+str(r)
        print b1
        print b2
        print ''
        #save offsets of the section of "different" bytes
        #data.append([diffOff, diffOff+off-1])  #[begin diff off, end diff off]
        if looking:
            d.write(str(diffOff)+" => "+str(diffOff+off-2)+"\n")
            looking = False
            r = readSize
            off = off + 1
        else:
            off = off + r

    else:
        if r == 1:
            looking = True
            diffOff = off
            off = off + 1 #continue reading 1 at a time, until u find a same reading
        r = 1  #it will shoot back to the last off, since we didn't increment it here



d.close()
f1.close()
f2.close()          

#add the diff ending portion to diff data offs, if 1 file is longer than the other
a = int(math.fabs(a))  #get abs val of diff
if a:
    data.append([big-a, big-1])


print data
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you try [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) and [`filecmp`](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) modules?

> This module provides classes and
>   functions for comparing sequences. It
>   can be used for example, for comparing
>   files, and can produce difference
>   information in various formats,
>   including HTML and context and unified
>   diffs. For comparing directories and
>   files, see also, the `filecmp` module.
>
> The filecmp module defines functions
>   to compare files and directories, with
>   various optional time/correctness
>   trade-offs. For comparing files, see
>   also the `difflib` module

.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably encountering encoding/decoding problems. Someone may suggest a better solution, but you could try reading the file into a `bytearray` so you're reading raw bytes instead of decoded characters:

Here's a crude example:

```
$ od -Ax -tx1 /tmp/aa
000000 e0 b2 aa 0a
$ od -Ax -tx1 /tmp/bb
000000 e0 b2 bb 0a

$ cat /tmp/diff.py 
a = bytearray(open('/tmp/aa', 'rb').read())
b = bytearray(open('/tmp/bb', 'rb').read())
print "%02x, %02x" % (a[2], a[3])
print "%02x, %02x" % (b[2], b[3])

$ python /tmp/diff.py 
aa, 0a
bb, 0a
```